# change data into different format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data like this:

```
df = data.frame(Variable=rep(c("f10","f21","f32"),each=5), 
                Year=rep(paste("20",11:15,sep=""),3),             
        V1=sample(1:5,15,replace=T),V2=sample(5:10,15,replace=T),V3=sample(5:10,15,replace=T))
```

```
   Variable Year V1 V2 V3
1       f10 2011  3  7 10
2       f10 2012  2  5  7
3       f10 2013  5  7  5
4       f10 2014  3  8  7
5       f10 2015  3  6  5
6       f21 2011  5  5  8
7       f21 2012  3  6  5
8       f21 2013  1  5  5
9       f21 2014  5  5  5
10      f21 2015  4  9  6
11      f32 2011  5 10  9
12      f32 2012  3  7  8
13      f32 2013  3  7  7
14      f32 2014  2  5  8
15      f32 2015  5  7  9
```

I want to transform Variable column into columns and take V1,V2,V3 as rows
The output should look like this:

```
  Year County f10 f21 f32
1 2011     V1   4   3   2
2 2011     V2   9  10   7
3 2011     V3   5   6   8
4 2012     V1   4   3   3
5 2012     V2   9   9   7
6 2012     V3   5   9   5
7 2013     V1   5   2   2
8 2013     V2   5   8   8
9 2013     V3  10   7  10
```

I tried with pivot_wider :
**df%>%
pivot_wider(names_from = Variable, values_from = -c(1,2))**
But not getting the desired output!

Any help will be great!

Comment: Maybe try `pivot_longer(cols = V1:V3)` then `pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Year, name), names_from = Variable, values_from = value)`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c('Variable', 'Year')), 
       Year + variable~Variable, value.var = 'value')

#    Year variable f10 f21 f32
# 1: 2011       V1   2   4   3
# 2: 2011       V2   9   6   5
# 3: 2011       V3   9  10   8
# 4: 2012       V1   5   3   1
# 5: 2012       V2   5   5   8
# 6: 2012       V3   5   9  10
# 7: 2013       V1   4   4   4
# 8: 2013       V2   9   5   7
# 9: 2013       V3   6   8   5
#10: 2014       V1   2   1   1
#11: 2014       V2   7   9  10
#12: 2014       V3  10   7  10
#13: 2015       V1   5   4   3
#14: 2015       V2  10  10   7
#15: 2015       V3   5   5   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `dcast` function from `reshape2` package:

```
reshape2::recast(df, Year+variable~Variable)

   Year variable f10 f21 f32
1  2011       V1   5   2   3
2  2011       V2   8   7   5
3  2011       V3   8   9   8
4  2012       V1   4   3   2
5  2012       V2   5  10   9
6  2012       V3   5   8   6
7  2013       V1   3   5   5
8  2013       V2  10   6   7
9  2013       V3   9   8   6
10 2014       V1   5   4   5
11 2014       V2   6   9   7
12 2014       V3   6   5   9
13 2015       V1   3   4   1
14 2015       V2   8   5   6
15 2015       V3   9   7   5
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete R base solution can be possible.

Simulated data

```
df = data.frame(Variable=rep(c("f10","f21","f32"),each=5), 
                Year = 2011:2015,
                V1 = sample(1:5,15,replace=T),
                V2 = sample(5:10,15,replace=T),
                V3 = sample(5:10,15,replace=T))
```

First reshape

```
df2 <- reshape(df, direction="wide", timevar="Variable", idvar="Year")
```

Reversing colnames

```
cln0 <- colnames(df2[2:ncol(df2)])

cln1 <- gsub("(\\w*).(\\w*)", "\\2.\\1", cln0)

colnames(df2)[2:ncol(df2)] <- cln1
```

Second reshape

```
df3 <- reshape(df2, direction="long", timevar="County", idvar="Year", varying=c(2:10))
```

Final sort

```
o = order(df3$Year)
df3[o,]
```

**OUTPUTS:**

```
   Variable Year V1 V2 V3
1       f10 2011  1 10  5
2       f10 2012  5 10  9
3       f10 2013  5  7  9
4       f10 2014  4  9  5
5       f10 2015  3 10  8
6       f21 2011  1  7  8
7       f21 2012  3  7  8
8       f21 2013  1  6  5
9       f21 2014  2  6 10
10      f21 2015  5  5  6
11      f32 2011  4  8 10
12      f32 2012  3  5  6
13      f32 2013  3  8  6
14      f32 2014  5  5  9
15      f32 2015  5 10  9

        Year County f10 f21 f32
2011.V1 2011     V1   1   1   4
2011.V2 2011     V2  10   7   8
2011.V3 2011     V3   5   8  10
2012.V1 2012     V1   5   3   3
2012.V2 2012     V2  10   7   5
2012.V3 2012     V3   9   8   6
2013.V1 2013     V1   5   1   3
2013.V2 2013     V2   7   6   8
2013.V3 2013     V3   9   5   6
2014.V1 2014     V1   4   2   5
2014.V2 2014     V2   9   6   5
2014.V3 2014     V3   5  10   9
2015.V1 2015     V1   3   5   5
2015.V2 2015     V2  10   5  10
2015.V3 2015     V3   8   6   9
```